# Bitbucket for source code using Maven and Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, bitbucket, pom.xml

I have a pom-file that downloads jars from Artifactory. But for debugging I would like to have the sourcecode, but this is not in artifactory. Is there a way to tell Intellij that the source code is in Bitbucket so that code can be used for debugging?

Comment: If these are your own jars, I would build them with attached sources in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to **attach sources** to corresponding Libraries that IDE downloaded from artifactoty and set up automatically:

[image]

But note that on any change of them in Maven configuration you will loose the manually set up sources since IDE re-imports configuration from Maven including for the libraries.

Otherwise I would recommend you to add sources to the artifactory repository or use the dependency on the Maven project (that has surces) instead of the library jar.